# Unable to set numeric value leading with zero as text using phpexcel

Tags: phpexcel

I have created an excel using PHPExcel library. Everthing going well but when i insert numeric value leading with zero then it removed the zero from that number.

```
                                foreach($option['option_value'] as $option_value){
                                $activeSheet->SetCellValue('A'.$row, $product['model']);
                                $activeSheet->SetCellValue('B'.$row, $product['name']);
                                $activeSheet->setCellValueExplicit('C'.$row, '0000', PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
                                if(empty($option_value['barcode'])){
                                    $activeSheet->SetCellValue('C'.$row, 'NA');
                                }else{
                                    $activeSheet->SetCellValue('C'.$row, $option_value['barcode']);                                        
                                }
                                $activeSheet->SetCellValue('D'.$row, $option_value['name']);
                                $activeSheet->SetCellValue('E'.$row, round($price,2));
                                $activeSheet->SetCellValue('F'.$row, $option_value['quantity']);
                                $row++;
                            }
```

I have used following inbuilt function to set column type as text but nothing got:

```
$activeSheet->getStyle('C1:C'.$row)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('00000');  or  
$activeSheet->getStyle('C1:C'.$row)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0');  or  
$activeSheet->getStyle('C')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
```

Can anyone tell me that what the thing i m doing wrong in above code? Is there any other alternative to fix the same.

Waiting for reply.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers don't have leading zeroes. Either you have a string of digits, the first of which are zeroes; or you **format** a number to **appear** with leading zeroes.

Either:

```
// Set the value explicitly as a string
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValueExplicit('C2', '0000', PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

or

```
// Set the value as a number formatted with leading zeroes
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('C3', 0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('C3')
    ->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0000');
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. I have applied your both solutions in our code but nothing has changed in excel. It still making column as a general format.

Comment: That should work for all writers; can you please add code to your question to show exactly how you are setting the cell values and styles at the moment

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question and putted what i have done to write data in excel. I am writing product bar code in column C and i want this column as Text so that if any bar code has 0 in starting then excel won't remove it.

Comment: So `option_value['barcode']);` is a string value or an integer?